# How is the API version done for https://graph.windows.net

Tags: azure-active-directory

How is the versioning done for https://graph.windows.net and https://graph.windows.net/$tenantdomain/activities

I see the  https://graph.windows.net/ has versions [latest is 1.6] ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-versioning#2013-11-08

but https://graph.windows.net/$tenantdomain/activities is still referred as beta version. The same holds good for /reports as well[https://graph.windows.net/$tenantdomain/reports].

Kindly let me know the difference in version of the above mentioned APIs

Thanks 
Karthick

Answer (score 1):

graph.windows.net is the older Azure Active Directory Graph API. graph.microsoft.com is the newer Microsoft Graph API.

I don't think that they will be making updates to the AAD Graph API, it seems all new development is focused on the MS Graph API. You can find documentation about it on https://graph.microsoft.io.

But even though, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to the activities API in the MS Graph API.

Comment: I agree, reached Microsoft tech support. But, found no informative data except to migrate to /activities API. /activities API is even more organized than /reports.